# Программирование загрузочного сектора C

Tags: c, ассемблер, gcc, boot

Разбираюсь с программированием загрузочного сектора. Делаю согласно [этой](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664165/Writing-a-boot-loader-in-Assembly-and-C-Part) статье. Всё получалось до момента программирования вывода "Hello, World!" на языке C. Вот код, который приводится в статье (собственно, я его просто копирую):

```
__asm__(".code16\n");
__asm__("jmpl $0x0000, $main\n");

void printString(const char* pStr) {
     while(*pStr) {
          __asm__ __volatile__ (
               "int $0x10" : : "a"(0x0e00 | *pStr), "b"(0x0007)
          );
          ++pStr;
     }
}

void main() {
     printString("Hello, World");
}
```

Компилирую, линкую и тд опять же согласно той статье:

```
gcc -c -g -Os -m32 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror test.c -o test.o
ld -melf_i386 -static -Ttest.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o test.elf test.o
objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin
dd if=/dev/zero of=floppy.img bs=512 count=2880
dd if=test.bin of=floppy.img
```

На всякий случай приведу содержимое test.ld:

```
ENTRY(main);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        *(.text);
    }
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE)
    {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }
}
```

Запускаю bochs, но вместо того, чтобы напечатать "Hello, World", у меня выводится только один символ "S".

Перенёс функцию в main:

```
__asm__(".code16\n");
__asm__("jmpl $0x0000, $main\n");
void main()
{
    char s[] = "Hello, World";
    char *str = s;
    while (*str)
    {
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
               "int $0x10" : : "a"(0x0e00 | *str), "b"(0x0007)
          );
        ++str;
    }
}
```

После этого он перестал выводить что-либо в принципе. Помогло исключение флага оптимизации -Os. Вывод стал верным. Немного поэкспериментировав, я понял, что эта оптимизация "убивает" цикл.

Однако, тот же самый код, но перенесённый в функцию, всё так же выводит символ "S".

Прошу помощи в решении этой проблемы. А так же, если возможно, разъяснения, почему флаг оптимизации "убивает" цикл. Спасибо!

**UPD.**

Hex от test.bin:

```
66 EA 3A 7C 00 00 00 00 66 55 66 89 E5 EB 19 67 66 8B 45 08 67 66 0F B6 00 66 0F BE C0 80 CC 0E CD 10 67 66 83 45 08 01 67 66 8B 45 08 67 66 0F B6 00 84 C0 75 D9 90 66 5D C3 66 55 66 89 E5 66 68 4F 7C 00 00 E8 C0 FF 66 83 C4 04 90 C9 C3 48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 00 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 7A 52 00 01 7C 08 01 1B 0C 04 04 88 01 00 00 1C 00 00 00 1C 00 00 00 8C FF FF FF 32 00 00 00 00 42 0E 08 85 02 43 0D 05 6C C5 0C 04 04 00 00 1C 00 00 00 3C 00 00 00 9E FF FF FF 15 00 00 00 00 42 0E 08 85 02 43 0D 05 4F C5 0C 04 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 AA
```

Файл был получен из следующего исходника:

```
__asm__(".code16\n");
__asm__("jmpl $0x0000, $main\n");

void printString(const char* str)
{
    while (*str)
    {
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
               "int $0x10" : : "a"(0x0e00 | *str));
        ++str;
    }
}

void main()
{
    printString("Hello, World");
}
```

**UPD.**

Результат дизассемблирования файла test.elf:

```
% objdump -d test.elf

test.elf:     file format elf32-i386

Disassembly of section .text:

00007c00 <printString-0x8>:
    7c00:   66 ea 3a 7c 00 00       ljmpw  $0x0,$0x7c3a
    ...

00007c08 <printString>:
    7c08:   66 55                   push   %bp
    7c0a:   66 89 e5                mov    %sp,%bp
    7c0d:   eb 19                   jmp    7c28 <printString+0x20>
    7c0f:   67 66 8b 45 08          mov    0x8(%di),%ax
    7c14:   67 66 0f b6 00          movzbw (%bx,%si),%ax
    7c19:   66 0f be c0             movsbw %al,%ax
    7c1d:   80 cc 0e                or     $0xe,%ah
    7c20:   cd 10                   int    $0x10
    7c22:   67 66 83 45 08 01       addw   $0x1,0x8(%di)
    7c28:   67 66 8b 45 08          mov    0x8(%di),%ax
    7c2d:   67 66 0f b6 00          movzbw (%bx,%si),%ax
    7c32:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
    7c34:   75 d9                   jne    7c0f <printString+0x7>
    7c36:   90                      nop
    7c37:   66 5d                   pop    %bp
    7c39:   c3                      ret    

00007c3a <main>:
    7c3a:   66 55                   push   %bp
    7c3c:   66 89 e5                mov    %sp,%bp
    7c3f:   66 68 4f 7c             pushw  $0x7c4f
    7c43:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    7c45:   e8 c0 ff 66 83          call   83677c0a <main+0x8366ffd0>
    7c4a:   c4 04 90                les    (%eax,%edx,4),%eax
    7c4d:   c9                      leave  
    7c4e:   c3                      ret
```

**UPD.**

Вот дизассемблирование hiew как просессор видит программу:

```
7c00: 66EA3A7C00000000              jmpf        00000:07C3A
7c08: 6655                         3push        ebp
7c0A: 6689E5                        mov         ebp,esp
7c0D: EB19                          jmps        000000028 --↓1
7c0F: 67668B4508                   2mov         eax,[ebp][8]
7c14: 67660FB600                    movzx       eax,b,[eax]
7c19: 660FBEC0                      movsx       eax,al
7c1D: 80CC0E                        or          ah,00E
7c20: CD10                          int         010
7c22: 676683450801                  add         d,[ebp][8],1
7c28: 67668B4508                   1mov         eax,[ebp][8]
7c2D: 67660FB600                    movzx       eax,b,[eax]
7c32: 84C0                          test        al,al
7c34: 75D9                          jnz         00000000F --↑2
7c36: 90                           nop
7c37: 665D                          pop         ebp
7c39: C3                            retn ;
7c3A: 6655                          push        ebp
7c3C: 6689E5                        mov         ebp,esp
7c3F: 66684F7C0000                  push        000007C4F ;'  |O'
7c45: E8C0FF                        call        000000008 --↑3
7c48: 6683C404                      add         esp,4
7c4C: 90                            nop
7c4C: 90                            nop
7c4D: C9                            leave
7c4E: C3                            retn ;
7c4F: 48 65 6C 6C 6F-2C 20 57 6F-72 6C 64  Hellow, World
```

Методом тыка, заметил, что действительно указатель необходимо смещать. Для загрузочной области необходимо поместить код в первый сектор диска со смещением в 0x7C00 байт. Это я указываю в файле test.ld. Я попробовал вывести всё, что у меня идёт после. И в куче разнообразных символов затаился желаемый "Hello, World". При этом изменение кода влечёт изменение в смещении, но я почти уверен, что оно будет всегда больше 0x7C00. Осталось понять, как правильно отслеживать это смещение...

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно сделать `DS=CS` приравнять слекторы, т.к. *pStr по умолчанию использует DS селектор. Например так  `__asm__("mov ax,cs\n"); __asm__("mov ds,ax\n");` В borland проще `_DS=_CS` или так `const char _cs * pStr`;

Comment: Почему 100h? бут-сектор при выполнении загружается в область памяти по адресу 0:7C00h. Причём физически именно туда, но вот какими будут CS:IP - это фиг знает. может быть и 7Ch:0, и ещё куча вариантов. Так что для настройки адресов и сегментов куда как разумнее собирать с `ORG 7C00h`, и начинать с `JMP NEAR $+xxh`, а там сразу `JUMP FAR PTR 0:label` по метке.

Comment: @Akina имелось ввиду что можно "потестировать" на com-файле, у которого смещение 100h, а потом перейти к более сложному написанию загрузчика. Он хорошо смотрится дизассемблером,  дебагером td.exe  трассируется и почти сразу видно ошибки.

Comment: @nick_n_a Спасибо за комментарии. Не знаю, на сколько это будет важно, но моя ОС - Linux. Попробовал приравнять DS=CS. Я использую синтаксис AT&T, следовательно у меня это выглядит как-то так __asm__("mov %cs,%ax\n");
__asm__("mov %ax,%ds\n"); Но, к сожалению, всё тот же символ S.

Comment: Тогда я вам рекомендую дизассемблировать код загрузчика, или попробовать, может компилятор умеет собирать asm-файл. Выложите дизассемблированый код (asm со всеми смещениями)  Тогда можно обьективно говорить что не так. Выложите хотя бы hex вашего img, того что у вас вышло - я вам дизассемблирую. Надеюсь у вас до 512 байт.

Comment: @nick_n_a привёл файл в hex-формате. Я так понимаю, что полученный test.bin файл полностью совпадает с floppy.img

Comment: @nick_n_a единственное, что наиболее простой метод (objdump -d test.bin) у меня не срабатывает. Видимо, потому что файл платформонезависимый. От test.elf файла срабатывает. Приведу результат в вопросе

Comment: Меня смутило что адресация у вас 32-битная. Попробуйте как-то собрать с 16-битной адресацией. Особо смущает строчка `000F: 67668B4508 mov eax,[ebp][8]` префиксы 67 говорят о 32-битной адресации с 16-битного режима. Ваш дамп вам не правильно результат дал. Не знаю почему. 8-это не верное смещение, должно быть 4. Там везде компилятор не правильно поставил смещение локальной переменной. Поэтому у вас и мусор на экран идёт. Можно поставить костыль типа `sub %bp,4 `, но собралось точно не верно, не знаю чего.

Comment: @nick_n_a я читал, что gcc как таковой не может скомпилировать 16-битный файл. Обходное решение - компилировать в x32 с указанием в начале файла директивы .code16. У меня x86_64 система, но компилятор может компилировать 32-битные файлы. Для этого я компилятору указываю флаги -m32 и -march=i386, а линкеру -melf_i386.

Comment: @nick_n_a Однако, вы натолкнули меня на правильный запрос в гугле) Видимо с обновлениями директива **code16** исчезла и на её место пришла **code16gcc**. Глупая ошибка. Простите, что потратил Ваше время. Вопрос решён.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае написание загрузочного сектора - проверяйте дизассемблером что у вас вышло. Для линукса незнаю как, для винды hiew.exe - хороший дизассемблер. Не забывайте что на старте - процессор находится в 16-битном режиме команд и в 16-битном режиме адресации - это важно 1) при сборке бинарника 2) для понимания что происходит 3)при дизассемблировании.

Анализ даного случая показал, что код "неправильно" собран то ли компилятором то ли линкером. Коды 66 - переход в режим 32-битной команды, и 67 - переход в 32-битную адресацию

```
7c22: 676683450801                  add         d,[ebp][8],1
7c28: 67668B4508                   1mov         eax,[ebp][8]
7c2D: 67660FB600                    movzx       eax,b,[eax]
```

эти переходы должны напрягать. Их использовать можно (66), но с умом. 32-битную адресацию (67) лучше избегать вообще, вплоть до переключения в защищенный режим, но первичный загрузчик этого не делает. Как вывод  - Если код не работает, хотя он проверен, а картинка не складывается - то проблема с опциями сборки.

Конкретно в даном случае помогло  поменять директиву `code16` (она в новой версии gcc исчезла) на  `code16gcc`. Указывать `code16` или  `code16gcc` зависит от версии GCC.